# Position text within an NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Cocoa noob here. I'm working with an `NSTextField`, and am using `CALayer` to style the border of it.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: how can I position where the input text actually starts? I'd like to be able to push it over from the left and the top a bit.

Thank you!

Comment: "Cocoa noob here." - but at least you used tagging correctly. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you solve this by creating a `NSView` container?
So it will look a bit like this: `NSView` with `CALayer` border and `NSTextField` inside.

You get the idea?